# Join table to a join table in CakePHP 3.x: associations and double-action

Tags: mysql, join, associations, cakephp-3.x

In [this example](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option) from the book I want to allow OTHER users to modify the field `days_attended` in `CoursesMemberships` join table, but only once a day. For this purpose I am going to make a new join table `CoursesMembershipsReviews` with `id | coursesmembership_id | student_id | created | modified` fields. The question is how to be with the associations? I would do:

- a student hasMany `CoursesMembershipsReviews` and belongsToMany `CoursesMemberships` through `CoursesMembershipsReviews`;
- a `CoursesMembership` hasMany `CoursesMembershipsReviews` and belongsToMany `Students` through `CoursesMembershipsReviews`;
- a `CoursesMembershipsReview` belongsTo `CoursesMemberships` and belongsTo `Students`.

I am a bit confused since the `CoursesMemberships` table is already a join table itself. Is this a right way?

The second concern is how to avoid a double-action while submitting a Form which would allow another user to change the field `days_attended`? He would need to `edit()` a `CoursesMemberships` and create/modify `CoursesMembershipsReview` at the same time if I want to check whether the last `modified` is 24h old. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the first answer I would do the following

- `Student`

  - hasMany `CoursesMembershipsReviews`
  - belongsToMany `Courses` through `CoursesMemberships`;
- `CoursesMembership`

  - hasMany `CoursesMembershipsReviews`
  - belongsTo `Students`
  - belongsTo `Courses`
- `CoursesMembershipsReview`

  - belongsTo `CoursesMemberships`
  - belongsTo `Students`

Anyway it's not clear in your question if 'once a day' is referred to the single user or to all user.

In other words: if a user edit the courseMembership is the edit forbidden also to other users for the next 24 hours or just for that user?

In the first scenario you don't even need a `courses_memberships_reviews` table (unless you want it). You just can store in the `course_memberships` table the information about who and when edited the record.

In the second scenario when you create the `CoursesMembership` entity you can attach a `CoursesMembershipsReview` entity containing the information of the user who created the `CoursesMembership` and save the two at the same time

Comment: thank you for the answer! So you suggest that neither Students nor CoursesMemberships do not belongTo each other through CoursesMembershipsReviews (the rest of associations above I had earlier), which makes life much easier. I do have a second scenario, but the CoursesMemberships are created by the student involved much earlier. Others will be able to modify days_attended in his record afterwards, and when they do this, I would need to add/edit a new CoursesMembershipsReview entity to perform my 24 hrs check. Which is still not clear to me how.

Comment: So you are saying that if I modify the days_attended then anyone but me is allowed to modify it again in the next 24h, right?

Comment: Correct. All other users can add days to this field, but only once a day.

Comment: You Can use validation to ensure that. You want to create an application rule. Ser data validation in the book

Comment: I thought about custom validation, but I would need to edit (or create if not exists) a record in CoursesMembershipsReviews first, in any case . Will it work if I do this in the controller and check by the vlaidation?

Comment: yes, you add a CoursesMembershipsReviews at the same time you create the CoursesMembership. You can save the two entities with justa a single save call. The validation rule wlll always check if there are other CoursesMembershipsReviews  for thet user in the last 24 h and don't let you edit the CoursesMembership otherwise